# Root of unity for $n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $n \ge 1$ and $u_{1},u_{2},...,u_{n}$ are all root of unity for $n+1$ and there are different from $1$.
> (a) Find polynomial $f \in \mathbb R[x]$ of degree $n$ for which: $f(u_{k})=0$ for $k=1,2,...,n$.
> (b) Calculate real coefficient and imaginary part for $(2-u_{1})(2-u_{2})\cdot...\cdot(2-u_{n}).$

I have a knowledge about root of unity but I completely don't know how to do it because I think that I need some extra trick to do it but my ideas finished. I know that $\varepsilon_n^{(k)} = \cos\left(\tfrac{2k\pi}{n}\right) + i\sin\left(\tfrac{2k\pi}{n}\right) = e^\frac{2\pi i k}{n}$ and for $n>1$ $\sum _{{k=0}}^{{n-1}}e^{{\frac  {2\pi ik}{n}}}=0$ but I think it is too little knowledge to solve this task.
Can you help me?

Comment: The $\ (n+1)^\mbox{th}\ $ roots of unit, by definition, are roots of the polynomial $\ x^{n+1} - 1\ $, one of whose factors must be $\ x-1\ $, corresponding to the root $\ x=1\ $.  What is the polynomial you get by dividing out this latter factor?  What are its roots?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I have a polynomial $f(x)=x^{n}+x^{n-1}+...+x+1$. Then I have $f(u_{k})=(u_{k})^{n}+(u_{k})^{n-1}+...+(u_{k})+1$ and I think I should use $ e^\frac{2\pi i k}{n}$ so I have $f(u_{k})=(e^\frac{2\pi i k}{n})^{n}+(e^\frac{2\pi i k}{n})^{n-1}+...+(e^\frac{2\pi i k}{n})+1$ but I don't know why this is equal to zero

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice that you had written  $\ e^\frac{2\pi ik}{n}\ $ for your $\ (n+1)^\mbox{th}\ $ roots of unity.  They should be $\ e^\frac{2\pi ik}{n+1}\ $.  What do you get if you multiply $\ f(u_k)\ $ (which should be $(e^\frac{2\pi ik}{n+1})^n +  (e^\frac{2\pi ik}{n+1})^{n-1} + \dots + e^\frac{2\pi ik}{n+1} +1$) by $\ e^\frac{2\pi ik}{n+1} -1$?  Is this multiplicand equal to zero?  If not, what can you conclude about the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $p(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+\dots+1$.  It is equal to zero at each $u_i$ because $p(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$.

For part $2$, calculate $p(2)$.  That is $p(2)=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2-1}=2^{n+1}-1$.